# Angular 2 - how to inject dependencies to custom class which is not a component and isn't exposed as service

Tags: typescript, angular

We're working here on pretty large scale app written in TypeScript and Angular 2 and I have a major problem understanding how to use Angular 2 injector in a custom way. Actually I am not sure if I'm trying to do something not intended by framework, but so far I've found only bad solutions to what I try to do...

So, what I'm trying to achieve is to apply  values from Injector to classes which are not incorporating @Component behavior and are not exposed to Injector as a Services, mapped to global or component level injector.
(I think I understand quite well how to inject stuff in those two scopes and that works just fine).

What I'm trying to is something like this:

```
export class SomeCustomClass {
    constructor(injection:InjectionToken) {
        console.log('injection', injection);
    }
}
```

And I do know that if I'd add this class to injector within bootstrap or as a part if @component decorator that would work nice. Problem is that it's not what I intend to do.

What I need is something like:

```
factory.createInstanceWithInjectionApplied(SomeCustomClass);
```

I actually could live with simple:

```
var instance:SomeCustomClass = new SomeCustomClass();
```

But that  doesn't seem realistic.

Oh, and yes I've already tried everything I could think of - @Injectable() do nothing on instances created like this, Injector.createAndResolve also doesn't seem to work and keeping kind of static property with access to application Injector does not seem like a nice idea either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you already found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to use the [`Injector`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Injector-class.html) class?

Here is a sample:

```
var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([Car, Engine]);
var car = injector.get(Car);
```

and another one:

```
export class SomeCustomClass {
  constructor(injector:Injector) {
    (...)
  }
}
```

Comment: That would create brand new injector without reference to parent that can, and actually, is injecting it self, but not something which is already defined within main `Injector`.

Comment: `var injector = appInjector.resolveAndCreateChild([SomeCustomClass]);
injector.get(SomeCustomClass));`


Does the trick. Also that would require existing reference to application injector, which is actually inevitable condition in order to apply injected values of it.


Thanks, I think I got it clear now!

Comment: You can get an instance of the app injector at the bootstrap level: `bootstrap(AppComponent).then((componentRef) => { console.log(componentRef.injector); });`. You need then to find a way to provide it where you want to use it...

Comment: I know that. Only problem is that this approach would kind of brake modularity. But I'll think of something.

Comment: Yes, agreed with you!

Comment: Please tell me How it is doing in angular 10+ ?